# CROSS JOIN alternative

Tags: sql

I have a result set already but I am interested in alternative queries with the same result. What can be better or faster between them?

```
insert into [dbo].[Teams]  values(1,'First')
insert into [dbo].[Teams]  values(2,'Second')
insert into [dbo].[Teams]  values(3,'Third')
insert into [dbo].[Teams]  values(4,'Fourth')
insert into [dbo].[Teams]  values(5,'Fifth')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Team_team] (
[id1] [int] NOT NULL,
[id2] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

select * from teams;

select t1.id,t2.id  from teams t2 cross join teams t1
```

Comment: You can pick any other join type `LEFT`, `INNER`,`RIGHT` and make the join predicate `ON 1=1`. Won't improve performance though.

Comment: You show the schema for `Team_team`, yet your sql is querying `Teams`.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` is the best way to represent an intentional Cartesian product... anything else would look like an accident.

Comment: I know that it is best. I mean compare another method between them. Except cross join

Answer (score 0):

This is the same with other syntax:

```
select t1.id,t2.id  from teams t1, teams t2
```

There won't be performance difference.

Comment: This answers the question, but a note about how this is syntax should be strongly discouraged would be nice...